# How vlookup between range values?

Tags: excel, formula, vlookup

I have this challenge!!

How can I solve the problem below (picture) using any formula?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=INDEX(D$3:D$11,MATCH(A14&B14,A$3:A$11&C$3:C$11,1)+1)
```

in C14 and copied down. It is an array formula to be entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Note that when at a break point it is the higher % that would be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula -1 (without year match)

```
=VLOOKUP(B14,$B$3:$D$11,3)
```

formula-2 (with year match)

```
=IF(MATCH(A14,$A$3:$A$11,0)>0,VLOOKUP(B14,$B$3:$D$11,3),"Not Matched")
```

Just copy and paste the above formula in C14 and C15. An easy method to get the answer.